# Not able to get output from python script when trying to run command on SSH server

Tags: python, ssh

My script is -

```
import paramiko
import sys
from subprocess import STDOUT
host=str(sys.argv[1])
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='88888',username='admin',password='888888',key_filename='88888')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('cpstat -f cpu os')
print(STDOUT)
ssh.close()
```

Here i am checking cpu usage of remote machine , but in output only -2 is printing everytime.
Please help how can i get correct output from this script.

Comment: You're printing the value of the `subprocess.STDOUT` constant, which is `-2`. You probably want to print the value of  `stdout`, the variable you're setting with `ssh.exec_command`.

Comment: your print(STDOUT) is not correct, you are not using subprocess at all. You may reach your scope though if you use print(stdout.channel.recv(nbytes)) where nbytes is the maximum amount of bytes that you want receive.

Comment: When i executing this print(stdout.channel.recv(nbytes)) i am getting output as --  b' '

Comment: `b''` is an empty bytestring, which means you received 0 bytes

Answer (score 0):

This is what your script should look like

```
import paramiko
import sys
host=str(sys.argv[1])
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='88888',username='admin',password='888888',key_filename='88888')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('cpstat -f cpu os')
if stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() != 0:
    print("Error encountered")
else:
    print("Got something")
    print(stdout.channel.recv(-1).decode('utf-8'))
ssh.close()
```

Comment: When i am executing this script output is coming blank.

Comment: When i executing this print(stdout.channel.recv(nbytes)) i am getting output as -- b' '

Comment: try adding print(stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()) before the stdout.channel.recv(-1) ... it should return the retcode of your command which should be 0 if successful. 
if you get b'' try 
stdout.channel.recv(-1).decode('utf-8')

Comment: yes I execute which you provided and output comes like this -   0
b"CLINFR0771  Config lock is owned by admin. Use the command 'lock database override' to acquire the lock.\n"
>>>

Comment: When i execute this print(stdout.channel.recv(100000).decode('utf-8')) output is coming blank.

Comment: It looks like it's working then. ^_^, if you are trying to override the lock and it's not possible from command line, you may need to change your approach from ssh to pyexpect

Comment: Now output is coming blank

Comment: Yes i get output 'Got Something'

Comment: Something must have changed between the time you've got --- CLINFR0771 Config lock is owned by admin. Use the command 'lock database override' to acquire the lock.\n" --- and the time you've got blank. You may try to see what do you get using plain ssh using - 
ssh user@host 'cpstat -f cpu os' and check if any difference

You may want to check what's returned by stderr.channel.recv(-1)
However, with regard to your question, how to print the output from ssh with python, I think that's been covered.